# List object get one more item return than the original data set in Blazor WASM

Tags: list, null, blazor

I have a parent component file with one list object.

```
<h3>Create Movie</h3>

<MovieForm Movie="Movie" NotSelectedGenres="NotSelectedGenres" OnValidSubmit="SaveMovie"/>

@code {

    private Movie Movie = new Movie() ;

    private List<Genre> NotSelectedGenres = new List<Genre>()
                                                {
                                                    new Genre()
                                                        {
                                                            Id = 1, Name = "Action"
                                                        },
                                                    new Genre()
                                                        {
                                                            Id = 2, Name = "Comedy"
                                                        },
                                                    new Genre()
                                                        {
                                                            Id = 3, Name = "Drama"
                                                        }
                                                } ;

    private void SaveMovie()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this works") ;
        }

}
```

then I insert child component named 'MovieForm' in it.

And then on debug mode, When I checked the length of 'NotSelectedGenres' it said total 4. (in child component)

```
    [Parameter]
    public List<Genre> SelectedGenres { get ; set ; } = new List<Genre>() ;
```

it has one more with value of 'null' than the original data set.

```
NotSelectedGenres
   _items    BlazorMoves.Shared.Entities.Genre[](4)
     0       BlazorMoves.Shared.Entities.Genre
     1       BlazorMoves.Shared.Entities.Genre
     2       BlazorMoves.Shared.Entities.Genre
     3       null
     length  4
```

Is this the right thing?

Comment: Nobaody can debug this for you. Do File|NewProject and recrerate this , then post the changes you made from the tempalrtes. See [mre].

Comment: @Henk Holterman Thank you for your comment, I am following one lecture from Udemy. I am not sure to share the code here. I think there is nothing to interrupt through parent and child component. I will try to check more deeply. Thx again.

Comment: The only reason why you have four entries is that somewhere in the code you haven't shown us you insert a new `Genre` into the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you add the first item to a `List` in .NET, it internally allocates an array of size 4. The allocated size increases automatically as required.

the `Count` property should return the correct number of items in the list, while `Capacity` returns the current internal size allocated.

[List<> docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0)

Comment: YES!! you're right. What I found yesterday it is..whenever I add up some more 'new Genre' into List...it multiplied the length each 4 times. So I assumed what the list object is. Thank you so much for your reply. It helps me perfectly.